# Meteor Project Run Issue

Tags: meteor

I get an unexpected error while running the `Meteor App`. I didn't get any idea about this.So please see the below error and suggest me what to do?

Run the app as below :

**Root Directory of Project > meteor**

Error :

```
punycode.js:239
                    for (q = delta, k = base; /* no condition */; k += base) {
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:891:14)
    at NativeModule.require (node.js:861:18)
    at url.js:22:16
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:892:5)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (node.js:861:18)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:297:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/request/node_modules/cookie-jar/index.js:11:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

That for loop looks wrong, that's probably what's happening. Nothing meteor related.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp